# Is it possible to change symbol images when a keyboard event happened?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4, keyboard-events

I know that it is possible in actionscript 3.0, but I cant figure what method to use for it. like when i press the left arrow key, then the object on the flash will change image from circle to square. Something like that... I tried to google this but I really cant find the answer or even an example.

I only saw this site that contains the keyboard events in AS3 http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#

Could anyone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Listen KeyboardEvent code sample:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyboard);

function onKeyboard(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var char:String = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    trace("ker pressed: ", char);
}
```